# Xamarin forms POC iOS app, is it possible to call a webservice every 5 minutes when app is not open or not in the background

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create an app that calls a web service every 5 minutes, I was able to achieve this with a timer when app is in foreground or is in background using `Device.StartTimer`, is it possible to call web service every 5 minutes if the app is closed?

Comment: Platform specific code is required to do this. On Android you could create a foregrounded `Service`. On iOS you could setup the app to do a background fetches (but the time intervals are controlled via iOS).

Comment: We have a native android app doing this, I am trying to create an app for iOS with same functionality. I am really new to mobile app development, from my reading I understood, background fetch works only when app is in background. In my case, I need to run  a code when app is terminated.

Comment: On iOS, if the app is user terminated, it stays terminated till the user runs it again. You should look at remote notifications, but that stills requires that the user opens the notification.

Comment: Read the Discussion section: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application (`However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.`)